# undefined method `accept_nested_attributes_for' for #<Class:0x007fc5844fd868>

Tags: nested-forms

I am using rails 4. I am trying add a nested form of address in user but its throwing error: undefined method `accept_nested_attributes_for' for #

User.rb

```
has_many :addresses
accept_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :allow_destroy => true
```

Address.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

form template

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.input :name, :hint =>(t "user.name_eg"), :label =>(t "user.name") %>
   <% f.fields_for :addresses do |addr| %>
       <p>
           <div>
                <%= addr.text_field :address %>
           </div>
       </p>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

controller

```
@user = User.new
@user.addresses.build
```

Please help what am I missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is "accepts_nested_attributes_for". You can read about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)